# How do I redirect custom url using htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I am migrating from Wordpress to a custom coded content management system and need help converting the old URLs using htaccess.

I have over 2000+ old articles with the following URL structure:

www.site.com/ID/post-title/

I need to redirect each post to a custom script that uses the post ID:

www.site.com/post.php?id=ID

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/?    [NC]
RewriteRule .* post.php?id=%1  [L,QSA]
```

It will map silently this:

`http://www.site.com/ID/post-title/`

To this:

`http://www.site.com/post.php?id=ID`

Where `ID` is not a fixed string but a variable that is passed as the `id` value to the script.

Comment: +1 although note that an `R=301` should be included in the rule if redirects are in fact needed.

Comment: Yes, but the idea is to leave the incoming URL showing in the browser's address bar and a redirect `R flag` will modify it. It has to be mapped silently.

Comment: I tried the above code but received a 404 error. How do I implement the r flag?

Comment: Like this: `[R=301,L,QSA]`, but why do you get a 404 error is the important question. Please copy-paste in a comment the tested URL in the browser's address bar. ¿Does the script `post.php` exist and if so, where it is located?

Comment: My goodness I forgot that post.php was only theoretical, and the actual file name was something else. Everything is working as it should, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. If you are satisfied with the answer, you should consider [**accepting**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it.